# Sending error by email

Tags: c#, log4net

I would like to receive my application errors on my mail. 
Loging error to File working corectly.

I use log4net in version 1.2.13. I read a lot of example in internet but none of them is working.
please help me and give me some suggestion what I should change, and improve.

This is my app.config;

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net debug="false"> <!-- RollingLogFileAppender-->
    <appender name="RollingFileMessages" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs/CSVReader.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="9"/>      
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>      
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>      
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %type.%method – %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender,log4net">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
      <to value="mail@gmail.com" />
      <from value="mail@gmail.com" />
      <subject value="log4net err msg - My ASP.NET app" />
      <smtpHost value="smtp.gmail.com" />
      <port value="587"/>
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <username value="mail@gmail.com"/>
      <password value="passw1"/>
      <EnableSsl value="true" />
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName} :: %level :: %message 
      %newlineLogger: %logger%newlineThread: %thread%newlineDate: 
      %date%newlineNDC: %property{NDC}%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger  name="WebAppLog">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileMessages" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>  
</configuration>
```

In my application :

```
public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("WebAppLog");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

log.Info(" Form1 : Info ");
log.Warn(" Form1 : Warn ");
log.Debug(" Form1: Debug ");
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please give me some suggestion ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to send the email(s) in "real-time" or log daily, then send a batch email?  Real-Time always sounds awesome... until that one day when a bug is found... in a loop... that gets hit by lots of users... at which point you've accidentally invented a spam engine ;-) I'd highly recommend putting in throttles and size caps from "day 1" just in case.

Comment: I think it could email sending one per day. I am conscious that email could be in spam folder, but for now it is no problem. Also I will be check the spam. Now I want to send some mail. but it doesn't work. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: I'm not worried about it landing in a spam folder, the concern is that if 100's or 1,000's of emails are going to be generated you could *essentially* spam yourself to death with a flood of emails.  If you send enough emails, ISPs will also potentially consider the "mass emailing" as a "spammy" behavior and may throttle and/or block delivery (or worse yet put your "sender" on a blacklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your smtp appender is set as `Lossy = true` which will prevent events from being sent; setting Lossy on an appender defers the decision of whether or not an event must be logged to an evaluator that you need to configure. By default no evaluator configured means that no message is logged.

Either add an evaluator (you only have `LevelEvaluator` by default in vanilla log4net) or set the lossy parameter to false. See [this blog post](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-8-Lossy-Logging.aspx) for more info on lossy configuration (which very well may be what you want, ie only receive mails when errors occur)

Comment: If this helps don't hesitate to mark this answer as correct. As an aside, I would recommend reading the linked blog post in depth, it contains a very good example on how to configure the logs on a production environment

Comment: I have one more question. How Can I hide the user name and password to my email. I try to use aspnet_reggiis.exe, but It doesn't work properly. Maybe is some possibilities to set it programmatically ?

Comment: I think you will to create a custom appender if you want to encrypt some data. By default appenders don't do anything fancy with the property values when parsed

Comment: Have you got any idea , how should I do?Could ypu give me some example?

Comment: The comments are not really the right place for this, and this is not really the same question. You should look into creating a custom appender a bit, then asking another question if you cannot find more info, but yes adding them programmatically is definitely possible